# Google Maps API - cannot click on a link in an infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, infowindow, marker

I've got a problem with InfoWindow in GoogleMaps API v3 in Javascript. I have successfully created an info window, I can set any content inside, but I want to put a hypertext link inside. It works fine, i put normally  tag to the setContent() method and the link appears in the window correctly. Unfortunately, it is NOT clickable - it has a correct link attached to it, but when I click on it, nothing happens. When I click on it by right button and select "Open in new windows", it works just fine. Can anyone find out a problem here? I've got a code as simple as follows:

```
var bubble;

... some lines not related to the bubble ...

bubble = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  maxSize: new google.maps.Size(500,250)
});

... other not related lines...
```

then I trigger it in an event that creates markers (works fine for the markers):

```
bubble.setContent('<a href="http://www.google.com">LINK</a>');

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
   bubble.open(map, marker)
});
```

where both "map" and "marker" are just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. I believe this is being caused because the infowindow content is dynamically inserted into the DOM as a div. I don't know why this exactly happens, but here is how I solved it:

1. Use jQuery (I was already using this - if you use an alternative js lib, there may be equivalent solution(s) for the same)
2. update the html links to also have a class defined (say class="infowindow_link")
3. Add a jQuery handler to capture the link and follow it

   `$(".infowindow_link").live('click', function(){
     window.location.href=this.href;
   });`

This 'live' call tracks changes to the DOM and attaches the listeners to any new links you insert. The window.location.href update is the normal behavior of following a link.